# Possible to use OR in contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views

I know with standard filters in Views I can select "AND "OR" etc. for multiple fields but I don't see this option for contextual filters.

Comment: I really think it is not possible using Views UI. Maybe writing your own module and implementing some Views hooks... but in that case I'd suggest to use the hooks to modify the filters, not the contextual links.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a module for that, [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or).

> The module provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR
>   conditions for contextual filters.
>
> How does it work?
>  
>   The handler is replaced in views which is used by
>   default. A new option will appear in settings page query. If the
>   option is enabled the query will be rewritten using operator OR.